# Позиция меток на шкале AxisY в MSChart

Tags: c#, диаграммы

У меня есть контролл MSChart, на нем изображен график

[image: исходное изображение]

как видно на рисунке, метки на оси OY (AixsY) центрированы на основании штрихов. как сделать так, чтобы метки были сверху штриха?
Я пробовала сделать сдвиг метки через свойство IntervalOffset,

[image: со смещением меток]

но в этом случае, метки сдвигаются вместе со значениями оси, а мне нужно чтобы значения остались неизменными. Тут я указала IntervalOffset = 3.

Мне нужно получить так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не предлагайте уменьшить размер MajorTickMark, мне нужно только поднять метки наверх.

Answer (score 0):

После некоторого времени поиска информации по этому вопросу, пришла к выводу, что изменить позицию надписей штрихов с сохранением значений нельзя. Поэтому пришлось использовать у оси OY (AxisY) функционал добавления CustomLabels.

```
CustomLabel label = new CustomLabel
{
   FromPosition = <Начальное значение для размещения метки>,
   ToPosition = <Конечное значение для размещения метки>,
   Text = <Значение метки>
};
```